# single-line constructor assignment in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart and I'm a little confused with this syntax:

```
  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

What's the name of this kind of inline statement?
Not sure about `super(key:key)` role here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the constructor that comes after the `:` is called an initializer list.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list

The `super` keyword allows you to refer to the superclass, which in this case is `StatefulWidget`. Here you are calling the default constructor of the superclass and passing in the key parameter.